# peewee connect docker-mysql failed

Tags: python, mysql, docker, peewee

I created a mysql docker image as:

```
docker run \
        --name mysql \
        -v /Users/pivdet/Downloads/backup/docker_mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d \
        -v /Users/pivdet/Downloads/backup/docker_mysql/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d \
        -v /Users/pivdet/Downloads/backup/docker_mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql \
        -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=piv123 \
        -p 3306:3306 \
        -d mysql
```

And started the server by `docker start mysql`

I could connect to the server in terminal: `$ mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P3306 -uroot -ppiv123`

But when I tried to connect it by using peewee:

```
import peewee

mysql_db = peewee.MySQLDatabase("websdl", host="127.0.0.1", port=3306, user="root", passwd="piv123")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mysql_db.connect()
```

There's an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models.py", line 6, in <module>
    mysql_db.connect()
...
peewee.OperationalError: (1045, u"Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: NO)")
```

The user information of my db would be:

```
mysql> select Host, User from user;
+-----------+------------------+
| Host      | User             |
+-----------+------------------+
| %         | root             |
| localhost | mysql.infoschema |
| localhost | mysql.session    |
| localhost | mysql.sys        |
| localhost | root             |
+-----------+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Have you added your home IP address to the list of "Allowable Hosts" on your site's management portal?

Comment: @Sandeep I am curious why I typed my IP as `127.0.0.1` in peewee, but error show as `172.17.0.1`.

Comment: No idea! Check if you have installed database driver. If not, you can do so by following command:

$ pip install pymysql

Comment: Can you connect using just plain old pymysql / mysql-python?

Comment: I believe the user's issue had to do with mysql 8 and sha256 auth being incompatible with the python driver.